# Bootstrap 5 > Album example > How to make sure all cards stay of equal width (maximum xxx width and maximum height)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In the album example at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/album/ Bootstrap is manuallyputting several cards into a row and columns.

My problem is that, if you have e.g. 8 cards, and only 7 fit on your screen. The 8th card will shift to the next 'line', but then it becomes extraordinarily big (wide).

What can be a fix please?

I am using a similar looping code (Jekyll):

```
<div class="py-4 bg-light album">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    {% for image in site.static_files %}
        {% if image.path contains 'images/galleries' and image.path contains include.albumname %}

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
          <a class="lightgallery-item" href="{{ image.path }}" data-sub-html="{% exiftag image_description, , {{ image.path }} %}" >
                <img src="/thumbnails{{ image.path }}" class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top img-fluid"/>
            </a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">{% exiftag image_description, , {{ image.path }} %}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Update/clarification

Here's a graphical representation (screenshot) of the problem:

[image]

As you can see the bottom 'row'/'line' (it's not really a seperate class-'row' in the sense of Bootstrap) became too large.

This is using the following large PNG: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Periodic_table_large.png

Here is another MWE snippet of the problem, without any Jekyll code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="py-4 bg-light album">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
Some image here.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
Some image here.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
Some image here.
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
Some image here.
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
Some image here.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you don't put this in full screen size and resize the window as small as you can, you will see the problem. See the following screenshot:

[image]

### Second update (troubleshooting)

The problem seems to have been that I had only `<div class="row">`

whereas I should have had something like

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4 g-3">
```

Is this the best solution? In fact all of my thumbnails are pre-cropped to 200px, so I want to have the cards stay maximum 200px in width no matter what.

The problem is that, with the code above, they could become quite large. For example in `row-cols-md-4` they can become very large if the (fluid) container they are in is 100 percent of the screen width. How do I prevent this?

In fact, I feel the cards should also be the same height, all of them. What is the best way to force this?

Comment: Can you please clarify? The bootstrap example has all the columns in a single `.row` container. Are you saying you want the columns to scroll horizontally is the screen isn't wide enough instead of wrapping?

Comment: @Zim Hi and thanks for your reply. You are right about the .row Thanks. Your suggestion actually sounds really helpful, to have an automatic change to horizontal scroll. How can we achieve this please?